# What does immutable variable in Haskell mean?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, immutability, ghci

I am quite confused with the concept of immutable variables in Haskell. It seems like that we can't change the value of variables in Haskell. But when I tried following code in GHCI, it seemed like the value of variables did change:

```
Prelude> foo x=x+1
Prelude> a=1
Prelude> a
1
Prelude> foo a
2
Prelude> a=2
Prelude> a
2
Prelude> foo a
3
```

Does this conflict with the idea of immutable variables?

Many thanks!

Comment: that doesnt work in my rple...

Comment: Try to put `a = 1; a=2` inside a `.hs` file and compile it with `ghc`...

Comment: GHCi commands are IO actions, so it's like if everything you type was inside a `do` block. Which means that subsequent assignment to the same name are like nested `let`s, you *shadow* the old binding.

Comment: Got it! Thank you. This confused me so much.

Comment: Also: try in GHCi (even in separate lines) `let a=4 ; let f x= x+a ; let a=0 ; f 2` and see `6` as an answer, confirming that the value of the old `a` was indeed not changed.

Comment: Here is a way to overcome the confusion. Haskell doesn't have variables, only values.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Haskell doesn't allow you to modify existing variables. It does, however, allow you to *re-use variable names*, and that's all that's happening here. One way to see this is to ask GHCi, using the `:i[nfo]` directive, where the variable was declared:

```
Prelude> let a = 1
Prelude> :i a
a :: Num a => a     -- Defined at <interactive>:2:5
Prelude> let a = 2
Prelude> :i a
a :: Num a => a     -- Defined at <interactive>:4:5
```

These are actually two entire seperate, different variables, which just happen to be called the same name! If you just ask for `a`, the newer definition will be “preferred”, but the old one is still there – one way to see this, as remarked by chi in the comments, is to use `a` in a function:

```
Prelude> let a = 2
Prelude> :i a
a :: Num a => a     -- Defined at <interactive>:4:5
Prelude> let f x = a + x
Prelude> let a = 3
Prelude> f (-2)
0
```

`f` never needs to care that you've defined a new variable that's also called `a`; from its perspective `a` was one immutable variable that always stays as it is.

---

It's worth talking a bit about why GHCi prefers the later definition. This does **not** otherwise happen in Haskell code; in particular if you try to compile the following module, it simply gives an error concerning duplicate definition:

```
a = 1
a = 2

main :: IO ()
main = print a
```

The reason that something like this is allowed in GHCi is that it works different from Haskell modules. The sequence of GHCi commands forms in fact a sequence of *actions in the IO monad*<sup>†</sup>; i.e. the program would have to be

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   let a = 1
   let a = 2
   print a
```

Now, if you've learned about monads you'll know that this is just syntactic sugar for

```
main =
   let a = 1 in (let a = 2 in (print a))
```

and this is really the crucial bit for why you can re-use the name `a`: the second one, `a = 2`, lives *in a narrower scope* than the first. So it is more local, and local definitions have priority. Whether this is a good idea is a bit debatable; a good argument for it is that you can have a function like

```
greet :: String -> IO ()
greet name = putStrLn $ "Hello, "++name++"!"
```

and it won't stop working just because somebody defines elsewhere

```
name :: Car -> String
name car | rollsOverAtRightTurn car   = "Reliant Robin"
         | fuelConsumption car > 50*litrePer100km
                                      = "Hummer"
         | ...                        = ...
```

Besides, it's really quite useful that you can “redefine” variables while fooling around in GHCi, even though it's *not* such a good idea to redefine stuff in a proper program, which is supposed to show consistent behaviour.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>As dfeuer remarks, this is not the whole truth. You can do some things in GHCi that aren't allowed in an `IO` do-block, in particular you can define `data` types and `class`es. But any normal statement or variable definition act as it were in the `IO` monad.</sub>

Comment: One thing missing: GHCi allows `data`, `newtype`, `type`, `class` and `instance` declarations, which are not allowed in Haskell `do` syntax.

Comment: Given that GHCi is an *interactive* environment it's an essential feature. how many times did it happen to mistype a definition? If everytime you do that you have to choose a completely new name you would easily end up with unreadable names like `myFunction7` where all previous definitiong of `myFunction` contain an error, and you have to remember to always add that `7` when using the correct definition...

Comment: Right. If that was required then we'd need to adapt a completely different workflow, probably something with explicit scoping.

Comment: GHCi's top level is really a lot more like ML's than like Haskell's, I think.

Answer (score 2):

(The other answer using GHCi is fine but to clarify it is not specific to GHCi or monads...)

As you can see from the fact that the following Haskell program

```
main =
  let x = 1 in
  let f y = x + y in
  let x = 2 in
  print (x * f 3)
```

prints `8` rather than `10`, variables can only be "bound", not "mutated", in Haskell.  In other words, the program above is equivalent (called *α-equivalent*, meaning a consistent change of the names of bound variables only; see https://wiki.haskell.org/Alpha_conversion for more details) to

```
main =
  let x1 = 1 in
  let f y = x1 + y in
  let x2 = 2 in
  print (x2 + f 3)
```

where it is clear that `x1` and `x2` are different variables.